# Array sort() gives wrong answer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have intervals in an Array when I tried to use sort() to sort then it gives me wrong answer and could not able to sort it.. does someone have any idea how can I sort this. 
here is what I tried

```
array=["1050-3000","150-250","1-49","3001-9999","251-400","401-600","601-1049","50-149"]
```

When I sort it:- `array.sort();`
It gives me this answer:-

```
["1-49","1050-3000","150-250","3001-9999","251-400","401-600","601-1049","50-149"]
```

but what I expect is:-

```
["1-49","50-149","150-250","251-400","401-600","601-1049","1050-3000","3001-9999"]
```

Comment: Nope, your expectations are wrong ... Use the argument of [.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function to manipulate the order.

Comment: @Teemu how will I give the expected value then

Comment: Also check this: http://www.asciitable.com/ When sorting strings alphabetically, this is the order of characters. Actually '-' preceeds numbers.

Comment: [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) works as designed. Your array contains strings, it sorts them by their dictionary order.

Comment: OK, Understand :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to `split` the string and compare the first element.

```js
let array = ["1050-3000", "150-250", "1-49", "3001-9999", "251-400", "401-600", "601-1049", "50-149"];

array.sort((a, b) => a.split("-")[0] - b.split("-")[0]);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to `split`, convert to `Number` and then compare

```
var arr = ["1-49","50-149","150-250","251-400","401-600",,"601-1049","1050-3000","3001-9999"];
arr.sort( ( a, b ) => ( 
     al = +a.split("-")[1],  //last of a, after split by -
     bf = +b.split("-")[0],  //first of b, after split by -
     al-bf ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace dashes and sort.  You don't need to split to get an array and then access the first position.

```js
var array=["1050-3000","150-250","1-49","3001-9999","251-400","401-600","601-1049","50-149"];

array.sort((a, b) => a.replace('-', '') - b.replace('-', ''));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what (a,b) does here and which value they took

Comment: @JustStartedProgramming `a, b` are the values within the array  that will be compared, for example: `a = "1050-3000"` and `b = "150-250"`, and so on.

Comment: and  a.replace('-', '') - b.replace('-', '') here - is used to compair  right?

Comment: @JustStartedProgramming basically to know is a > b, i.e: `"10503000" > "150250" = true`

Comment: I appreciate your explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

The sorting function is giving you the right output because they are strings, not numbers. You will have to write custom logic to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `split` the dashes so as to compare the values in the array when using the `array.sort();` function

Here, try this:

```
var array = ["1050-3000", "150-250", "1-49", "3001-9999", "251-400", "401-600", "601-1049", "50-149"];

array.sort((a,b) => a.split("-")[0] - b.split("-")[0]);

console.log(array);
```